# In Language Flutter ,Every time I run an app with audio file . The audio file doesn't play . Show this long error s

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
E/flutter ( 6606): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Unexpected error!, Changing the playback rate is only available for Android M/23+ or using LOW_LATENCY mode., java.lang.IllegalStateException: Changing the playback rate is only available for Android M/23+ or using LOW_LATENCY mode.
E/flutter ( 6606):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.MediaPlayerPlayer.setRate(MediaPlayerPlayer.kt:45)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.configAndPrepare(WrappedPlayer.kt:307)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.player.WrappedPlayer.setSource(WrappedPlayer.kt:31)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:91)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin.access$handler(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:25)
2
E/flutter ( 6606):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$onAttachedToEngine$1$1.invoke(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:41)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at xyz.luan.audioplayers.AudioplayersPlugin$safeCall$1.invokeSuspend(AudioplayersPlugin.kt:62)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
E/flutter ( 6606):  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)

[This is the error showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLvsp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the error, it suggest that changing playback rate is only supported on android 23+. So you can remove that part of code or in your gradle file change minSdk to 23. Or as error suggest use low latency mode this parameter is available in the ‘play’ function.